# Remove the UrbanAirShip from ios project for push notification

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification

Hello i am working on live project, there are using "http://urbanairship.com/" for push notification , and my task is that replace it by "parse.com" so can any body tell me how can i do it?,  which method and framework need to remove or replace for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleas follow the steps.

1. You have to first remove urbanairship SDk in your app.
2. Compile it, you found some error.
3. Remove the import urbanairship scope and it's objects.
4. [Study the parse document](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS)
5. Integrate parse